# Installing SQLite On Mac OSX - Or, Is There A Recommended Alternate DB?

Tags: macos, sqlite

I'd like some advice on SQLite in OSX Snow Leopard.

I've read a gazillion posts and, of course, nearly all tell of the problems, and not the solution.  Before attempting an install that may lead to problems, **I'd like to get the "*Here's how to do it*" that works**.

I do have MySQL installed and can use it in Netbeans.

I also use SQLite as part of my Android app programming (via Eclipse).

I also use the database that comes with Netbeans/java but, it requires going through lot's of hoops to run it outside the NB IDE.

I also use Base (the OpenOffice database).

Although I can easily turn on/off MySQL from the convenient add-on to the Sys Pref's, it is a memory hog and memory isn't released after turning off the connection and turning it off. Also, I don't really need it's power for my minimal db needs so, I'd like to use a smaller footprint, such as SQLite.

**Some Questions**:

1. Since I use SQLite with Android, is it available to use in standard Java from Eclipse **?**  How about from Netbeans **?**  (I prefer Netbeans for standard java programming). And, how to run it outside Eclipse/Netbeans IDE **?**.
2. Where can I find the Simplest install instructions **?**
3. Is there a GUI interface available that enables basic db create/query...etc (What and where to find it **?**). Perhaps even a tutorial... I'd like to be able to work with a database as a stand-alone rather than through a cumbersome IDE.
4. Is there an alternate stand-alone **?**

Thanks - any input is much appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, sorry if you already knew that : SQlite is an embedded database, which mean it is only a file somewhere on the filesystem. All you need to use a SQLite database is a language with a database connector that will convert your SQL statement in read/write in the file format. So their is no "install" per say, except maybe to create a file somewhere . And even then, connecting to an existing file will create it for you in most library! And it will not use memory, since all the operation are executed inside your app. (EDIT well it will increase the memory footprint of your app, of course)

Of course, the downside is that only program on the same machine can connect on the database.

So to answer your questions.

1- Yes, you can use SQlite from standard Java. You just need to use a JDBC driver. Here is one http://www.zentus.com/sqlitejdbc/ that is fully managed (it run entirely in the java VM)

2- Connect a file somewhere on your computer. If it doesn't exist, it will create it for you. If you do that, you will then need to create your table in your code. I don't how much simpler it can get to be honest. The JDBC driver is installed like any other. You can also create the file manually with a GUI editor if you wish.

3- I haven't found a SQLite plugin in the official plug-in list of Netbeans, but I have found this http://netbeans.dzone.com/announcements/sqlite-jdbc-driver-plugin, which seem to be very, very beta, so I would be cautious before using is.

4- Since I always use SQlite purely in code, I can't recommend any GUI tool in particular. Other people may know more. There is this http://saxmike.com/MySoftware/MySoftware.asp?Menu=MYSOFTWARE, but the page has an animated gift, so...

Good luck with all  that!

Comment: No problems! I must have edited my answer 10 time to correct spelling mistake, I don't seem to perfectly master the english language yet.

Comment: Sort of quick follow-up... Have only downloaded/installed the GUI (your #4, above) but, it's perfect!  Simple, does what I need for a stand-alone db.  Being a programmer, I'll check out the JDBC driver so I can do my own GUI's...  Thanks again!

Answer (score -1):

Terminal:

```
 curl -O http://www.sqlite.org/sqlite-3.3.6.tar.gz
 tar xzvf ./sqlite-3.3.6.tar.gz
 cd sqlite-3.3.6
 ./configure --prefix=/usr/local
 make
 sudo make install
```

Comment: Thanks. First, I have the .zip, not .tar.gz (though, I could download it). However, before proceeding with your recommendation, I need some more info to get warm a fuzzy, as I've read too many posts with similar instructions that lead to many follow-on posts re problems... If it went well, how to interface to  it... etc

Comment: Don't that install the C version of SQLite? Since he is programming in java for Android, he may require a fully managed driver that don't require native code.